# Images do not exist even though they're in the folder

Tags: reactjs, image, file, path

I'm creating a React app with Vite and my images are stored in the public folder of my app and are accessed with public/image-name or .public/image-name. When I run the code locally all of them display but when I build and try to deploy the page on GitHub or see the preview with `npm run preview` all of them disappear.

It's definitely not the path problem since I've checked every single possible combination of relative and absolute paths. When I import the image to react with `import img1 from 'public/beagle.jpg'`, I get **Failed to resolve import "public/beagle.jpg" from "src/modules/CardDiv.jsx". Does the file exist?** and it clearly exists because I used it locally. When clicking on the file in VSCode GUI nothing appears, a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute paths are not available by default, they need to be configured with a compiler like TypeScript. Don't import assets from your public folder, those assets are exposed statically (http://example.com/beagle.jpg). Instead, put the image in the same directory you want to import from:

```
modules/
├─ CardDiv.jsx
├─ beagle.jpg
```

Then in `CardDiv.jsx`:

```js
import beagle from "./beagle.jpg";

const Component = () => <img src={beagle} />;
```

Note: this has nothing to do with React. This is handled by your build system in your case Rollup via Vite.

**Edit:** as Milan Patel pointed out, read the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory) for more information about the public directory.

Comment: For more information you can check out the doc https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory. It has detailed explanation.